# Text won't center when I run center() command

Tags: python, string, text, ms-word, python-docx

I'm trying to center text within a table, I managed to remove the empty space from the beginning/end of the string with .strip(), but .center() isn't working when I try to run it. Could someone tell me why/how to fix it? Code and current output is attached.

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
from docx.shared import Pt
from docx.enum.table import WD_CELL_VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT
from docx.enum.text import WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT

doc = Document('test.docx')
new_doc = Document()
sections = new_doc.sections
for section in sections:
    section.left_margin = Inches(3)
    section.right_margin = Inches(3)
for para in doc.paragraphs:
    para.alignment = WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.CENTER
    table = new_doc.add_table(rows=1, cols=1)
#    table.vertical_alignment = WD_CELL_VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT.CENTER
    table.style = 'Table Grid'
    text = para.text.strip()
    # get = int(len(text))
    # run = text.center(int(get), ' ')
    # for para.text in text:
    #     get = int(len(text))
    cells = table.rows[0].cells
    cells[0].text = text
#    cells[0].vertical_alignment = WD_CELL_VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT.CENTER
    paragraph = new_doc.add_paragraph('')
    paragraph.paragraph_format.space_after = Pt(0)
new_doc.save('details.docx')
```

Output: [image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

Passing `len(x)` to `center` makes it a no-op.

```
>>> 'hi'.center(len('hi'), ' ')
'hi'
>>> 'hi'.center(20, ' ')
'         hi         '
```

You could split by lines and center for some given width, but that isn't ideal, as you have to choose the width yourself, and potentially even split lines / do word-wrapping (when the document already has this logic).

You probably want to do this in word itself:
e.g. searching for "python docx center text" gives
https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/enum/WdAlignParagraph.html

```
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH

paragraph = document.add_paragraph()
paragraph.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
```

You could likely apply the same in your code as

```
para.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
```

Comment: so how would I go about fixing that? I need the distance to be the length of the string I'm calling automatically, as I will be utilizing this code for a number of different word documents with different length paragraphs.

Comment: I've added updated code. I'm using an integer value in the .center() command, but it's still not working as intended in the output.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to do?  (Perhaps like "justified" text in a text formatter, where the words are centered or spaced out within the line?)  Why not do this with CSS/HTML/Document itself?

Comment: If you look at the current output, I'm just trying to center that text within each of their respective boxes. This program is going to be used for x amount of documents at random with random length paragraphs/information within it. Additionally, I only really know python. So I want the text vertically centered in the middle of the (1x1) table that those paragraphs are in. I hope that's more clear for as to what I want. Also, I can give you images of what I want? I don't mind if I have to use a different library or something, I just want to vertically align the text within the tables.

Comment: Did you re-read my answer to see if it addresses your problem?

Comment: Sorry about that, I somehow managed to miss that. I've edited the post and there is the current text. I have the same output, however the paragraphs aren't aligned still. I have commented out some code that I was using that also wasn't doing anything.

Comment: What you do above seems strange, you would need to center the text of the table cell, since you are stealing it from the paragraph and making it an empty string afterwards.  Try reading some documentation here: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/table/table-cell.html?highlight=table%20align%20center#wd-align-vertical-enumeration

Comment: In the code I've got, I've commented out some lines where I attempted to do just that. I was still getting no results.   Some of the stuff from python-docx, like the WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER, is changed slightly, so in that case it would actually be WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.CENTER, but that doesn't work, and neither does WD_VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT.CENTER, for some reason.